# How to recover if bot_access_token gets lost during app installation due to an unexpected error?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am inegrating slack on my server in order to handle the [OAuth 2.0 install flow](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) for my Slack App as well as the bot-functionality that comes with it.

Everything is clear to me except one thing. The docs state the following about the *verification*/*authorization* codes which are send in exchange for the `code` I am receiving through the redirection link I provided:

> Authorization codes may only be exchanged once and expire 10 minutes after issuance.

If I understand this correctly, this means that if my server misses this authorization code, or simply does not manage to store the `access_token` or the `bot` credentials in my database, the user basically receives a half-dead app. Is that correct?

The user will still be able to run slashed commands e.g. `/help` but my bot won't work because I lost the `bot_user_id` and the `bot_access_token`.

So the question is whether this is accurate, and if not, how am I able to recover these credentials or do I really have only one shot here?

Comment: I would just tell the user that installation failed and ask him to repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your app somehow fails to receive or store the token during the installation process it will be installed (e.g. slash commands will be working, you will receive events), but you will be missing the token to call any API methods for that workspace.

To recover from this situation you should tell the user on your webpage, where he clicked the "Add To Slack" button, that the installation failed and that he should retry (e.g. click the "Add To Slack" button again). You would normally show the user the result of the installation process on your web page, which might also include standard "errors", like when the user canceled the process on the Slack side.

In addition you may want to show a user error for every slash command. You would normally have that anyway if your slash command tries to perform API calls, but it might make sense to also include an error to all the ones that does not (e.g. help or version sub commands).

Comment: But how? From what I can see, the moment I exchange the `code` for the `access_token`, the app counts as installed not matter what happens after that.

Comment: ok. the worst case would be: you send the post code, slack receives your request, registered your app as installed and replies with a token. But your app never receives the reply. Then you obviously should show the user an installation error (e.g. after a time out). The user will also normally just reinstall your app if something is not working. Finally if you are really really concerned about this scenario, just disable all functions of your app when this happens. This will force the user to reinstall.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover the worst case and how to recover / react to it. Please let me know if that solves your issue or if you need anything else.

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand what you meant by "*To recover from this situation you should tell the user on your webpage, where he clicked the "Add To Slack" button*". It's a bit weird because there is a chance that the user installs my app and does not follow or get the instruction to re-install it. At this point the user would have installed an app which partially works (e.g. some slash-commands) but all of team-id requiring features won't work and the user might not know why or won't realize he or she has to reinstall the app. Anyway, I know more now. Thanks for the explanation!